# ECMA 2015: how to use async functions with "yield" in a callback-routine?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, redux-saga

In an ECMA-2015-App (concrete: React Native) using [Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux) and [Redux-Saga](https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga) we have constantly a huge usage of code like this (which works fine and is not really the issue here):

```
const stats = yield call([dataStorage, dataStorage.loadPrefetchingStats], languageId);

yield put({type: ACTIONS.R_SYNCHRONIZE_STATE_PROGRESS, payload: {max: statsUnfetched, value: statsFetched}});

try {
  yield importRecord(languageId, record, dataStorage)
}
catch(err) {
  console.log("ERROR: ", err)
  yield put({type: ACTIONS.R_SYNCHRONIZE_STATE_ERROR, payload: err});
  return false;
}
```

Short question here: is there - however - any possibility to combine async functions and yield-constructs within callback functions?

**The longer question:**

To work with a local sqlite-database on the users device we use this fantastic library [react-native-sqlite-storage](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage).

To encapsulate multiple sql-statements within a transaction, callbacks are necessary like this:

```
        this.db.transaction((tx) => {

            var sql = `UPDATE product SET prefetched=?, error_prefetching=0 WHERE id=?`;

            return tx.executeSql(sql, [
                product.prefetched,
                product.id
            ], (tx, results) => {
            }, (a, b) => {
                console.log('ERROR', a,b);
            }) ;

        });
```

It is well known and best practice to speed up sqlite on many many INSERTs or UPDATEs when all these statements are encapsulated within a large single transaction.

But since we are using redux with lots of "yield"-statements to communicate between business logic and UI-Updates, we have a problem now.

Has someone an idea here?

Comment: *"but unfortunately it is not meant to be used in a callback function."* That's not correct this way. `yield` can only be used in generators. So if the callback function is a generator, you can use it. It seems your question is rather how to integrate "traditional" async functions using callbacks with redux-saga.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing Felix Kling stated. AFAIK, yield is used within generator functions. You might also try async/await

Comment: I think you can create redux-saga's channel and in your callbacks, no matter how deeply nested they are, you can put messages into this channel (or different channels, since there is no matcher feature for taking from channel). Then in your sagas you can `yield take` messages from this channel just as you take redux actions.

Comment: "await" isnt also not allowed in traditional callback methods. The thing is: there are lots of async generator functions, and some of them i want to reuse in traditional callbacks

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to handle callbacks in generators. The better method would be to `Promisify` your callbacks and then you could handle the promises using `yields`.

Consider a function that looks like this:

```
function doSomething(data,callback) {
   ...
   ...
   callback();
}
```

If you promisify it :

```
function promisedDoSomething(data) {
   return new Promise( (resolve) => {
      doSomething(data, resolve);
   }
}
```

Now you can use this promisified function in generators and just using it with `yield`.

```
var response = yield promisifiedDoSomething(data);
```